# Unban sending dm from user

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Is it possible when someone I unban, my bot automatically send the person a direct message even were not in the same server? Because I tried this It's unbanning but not sending a direct message to user

Comment: The bot needs to have a shared guild with the unbanned user to send him a DM.

Comment: So it's impossible to DM the user if were not in the same guild or have a shared guild?

Comment: Yup, sadly and not sadly, imagine bots can DM every Discord user, problems!

Comment: Make sense, thanks! anyway how can I close this thread?

Comment: You can validate my answer, I didn't found source however.

Comment: @新Acesyyy there is a `Delete` button for your post. It only takes one vote for the OP to delete the post

Comment: @MrMythical When I delete my first post, I got blocked about asking another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord bots and users can only DM another user if they have a shared guild or are friends, bots don't have friends so it won't be possible.